# How to go about creating a json translation feature, in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I am working on a project (the tech is Django Framework), and I have been assigned a task to create a functionality to store translations and create new translations of a given json file. The json file includes key, value pairs where the key is a unique key that the front-end of the app uses to tell where the text goes, which is the value. For example, { 'restaurant.wait':'Please wait while we process your order'}. So, I have a default json file with keys and values in English, and say we need a translation, I need to be able to get the values (easy part), show them to the translator, then he will input translations in a form with the translation for the given text. Now here comes the hard part, I need to then take this translation and map it back to the same keys in the json file. Another feature that this needs to have is to be able to export/import csv files of translations and then dynamically add them. I can't seem to figure out how to start solving this problem. I tried thinking of a model that I could have to hold the keys and to have another model that would be the translations, but I get confused how I should input the default values. I've just come to a stalemate on this problem and I am having a hard time thinking up of a clean way to do this. I also tried to go about it without a model for a database and just use a view to do this, but there is a problem with keeping order of the keys, and mapping the translations back to the correct keys. Please, I would really appreciate any help I can get with how I should go about to implement this. Thank you, in advance I hope there is enough detail that you can understand the issue I am having.